# How do I get Edge's current active tab's URL and title in bash?

Tags: bash, terminal, microsoft-edge, chromium, microsoft-edge-chromium

How do I get Edge's current active tab's URL and title in bash?

I can use `chrome-cli info` to do this on Chrome:

```
$ chrome-cli info

Id: 1680538140
Window id: 1680535647
Title: GPT-4 - Poe
Url: https://poe.com/GPT-4
Loading: No
```

Comment: Update: `CHROME_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER='com.microsoft.edgemac' chrome-cli ...` works.

Comment: https://github.com/prasmussen/chrome-cli